# iMacros SAVEAS (with TYPE=CPL or HTM) not saving the exact code of the page

Tags: imacros

I am running an iMacros macro that navigates a web site and saves a page to a file. I'm using a simple script as follow:

```
URL GOTO=http://myurl.com/    
SAVEAS TYPE=HTM FOLDER=* FILE=*
```

The issue is that the saved HTML page is different than the one I get when saving from Firefox using File -> Save page as... and selecting "Web Page, HTML only". It seems like some processing is done on the page by iMacros I suppose. For instance this line

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

becomes

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

This looks minor but on some occasions I had element that were reversed, hence hiding an issue with a tag wrongly closed. For example, where my page had

```
</form></div>
```

it was saved as

```
</div></form>
```

by iMacros.

Unfortunately I cannot find any reference of this issue on the iMacros forum. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
URL GOTO=http://myurl.com/    
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=CLASS:* EXTRACT=HTM
SAVEAS TYPE=HTM FOLDER=* FILE=*
```

Also a good and easy way to test extracted data is www.jsbin.com

Comment: I tried your code and the output is still different than what I get when I save the page directly from FF. It looks the same than when I do "SAVEAS TYPE=HTM FOLDER=* FILE=*" but it is written in a .csv file without any carriage returns.

Comment: From: http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS - "The value of the variable !EXTRACT is saved in CSV format."

Answer (score 0):

Work for me.

**Before start script create directory d:\reports or other**

```
 URL GOTO=http://your_url 
'Uncomment for not show popup
'SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=CLASS:* EXTRACT=HTM
SAVEAS TYPE=HTM FOLDER=d:\reports FILE=1.html
```